# How to enable two finger click on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: touchpad, 19.04

After updating Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, two-finger click doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via Gnome Tweaks.
If you don't have Gnome Tweaks installed, you can install it via Ubuntu Software.
Once it is installed, open it then go to Keyboard&Mouse section.  At the bottom, you will find **Mouse Click Emulation**. Check **Fingers**  As shown below

[image]